# Unit normal of sphere in cartesian coordinates

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm trying to find the unit normal of the following sphere: $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$
\begin{equation}
\vec{n}=\frac{\nabla \vec{g}}{|\nabla \vec{g}|}\\
\nabla \vec{g}=2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+2\hat{z}\\
|\nabla\vec{g}|=\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2}\\
\text{and finally } \vec{n}=\frac{2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+2\hat{z}}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2}}
\end{equation}
However the equality book give me at a point $S(x_0,y_0,z_0)$;
\begin{equation}
\vec{n}=(x_0\hat{i}+y_0\hat{j}+z_0\hat{k})
\end{equation}

Comment: Pull the $4$ out of the square root.

Comment: $x^2+y^2+y^2=1$  Simplify your expression.

Comment: oh my god. How did I miss that :D Thanks. I missed $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this case since $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

$$\vec{n_1}=\frac{x_0\hat{i}+y_0\hat{j}+\hat{z_0}}{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2}}\,=\,\vec{n_2}=x_0\hat{i}+y_0\hat{j}+z_0\hat{k}$$

In more general case for $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ we have $n_1\parallel n_2$ are parallel and both are two normal vectors to the surface with the difference that $\vec {n_1}$ is normalized (length=1).